# Cannot start fpm using phpbrew on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx

I have installed phpbrew and its dependencies, however I am having trouble testing fpm using the stated command:

```
phpbrew switch 5.4.38
sudo phpbrew fpm start
Did you mean 'app'? [Y/n] n
Command fpm not found. available commands are: help, zsh, bash, meta, compile, archive, github:build-topics, app, init, known, install, list, use, switch, each, config, info, env, extension, variants, path, cd, download, clean, update, ctags, list-ini, self-update, remove, purge, off, switch-off
Command: command not found
```

obviously I have gone wrong somewhere but cannot find why it will not fire up. I can confirm it is there

```
cd ~/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/sbin
ls
php-fpm
```

Install command:

```
phpbrew install 5.4.38 +fpm +mysql;
```

Info:

Version
PHP-5.4.38

Constants
PHP Prefix: /home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38
PHP Binary: /home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/bin/php
PHP Default Include path: .:
PHP Include path: .:

General Info

```
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.38

System => Linux dmdell02 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64
Build Date => Mar 10 2016 15:29:28
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38' '--with-config-file-path=/home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/var/db' '--disable-all' '--enable-phar' '--enable-session' '--enable-short-tags' '--enable-tokenizer' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--enable-fpm' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--enable-dom' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-xml' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-xsl' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc
Loaded Configuration File => /home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/php/php-5.4.38/var/db
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Extensions
Core, date, ereg, libxml, pcre, zlib, dom, SPL, session, standard, Reflection, mysqlnd, SimpleXML, Phar, mysqli, tokenizer, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, xsl, mysql

Database Extensions
mysqlnd
mysqli
mysql
```

Comment: That might be because `sudo` changes your PATH environment. Did you try running it with `sudo -E` ?

Comment: Thank ES - could you clarify this further as this is pointing to what might be the answer, running phpbrew commands simply as the user seem to work ok (except 9000 in use error, but thats just config). I installed as sudo so why this issue ?

Comment: @Evgeny Oh - I installed phpbrew as sudo but not the php version `phpbrew install 5.4.38 +fpm +mysql`

Comment: answered separatly. There was not enough symbols to leave as comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with all this trying to use OSX as a dev server.

Now using PHPStorm and pure VirtualBox Ubuntu server install. Price for personal PHPStorm and its features is amazing. Community support also.

Tried Vagrant but its crap and the fact it bodges DNS and port forwarding is not a proper representation of a remote host - we want to test as much as possible on modelled servers or real ?

Therefore the answer is to view both Windows and OSX unable to provide industry webserver config, and install a virtual machine with Linux as the server.

I now edit with PHPStorm on shared directory with VM, using the Zero Configuration facility bookmarklets in Chrome to debug PHP.

This is turning into a perfect dev setup on board an OSX laptop (my main aim) but can be used anywhere as all GIT based.

Happy to provide hints, but considered this question answered by me.

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed phpbrew iteslf using sudo that wont help. phpbrew relies on [getPhpbrewHome](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/blob/master/src/PhpBrew/Config.php#L15) function everywhere.

Unless you explicitly define PHPBREW_HOME with `PHPBREW_HOME=/blah phpbrew ...` it will use your HOME environment variable to generate installation/execution paths. But running sudo overrides HOME unless you tell it to preserve environment with -E: `env |grep HOME` => `/home/vagrant`,  `sudo env |grep HOME` => `HOME=/root`, `sudo -E env |grep HOME` => `HOME=/home/vagrant`.

In other words it searches for php binaries in `/home/datamechanics/.phpbrew/` when you run it as regular user and in `/home/root/.phpbrew/`if you run it with sudo

Most likely you have 3 option to solve your issue:

1. install php using sudo `sudo phpbrew install 5.4.38 +fpm +mysql`
2. run `phpbrew fpm` with your current user
3. explicitly set PHPBREW_HOME while running it with sudo `sudo PHPBREW_HOME=/home/datamechanics/.phpbrew phpbrew fpm start`

Comment: I have started down your option 1 route already. Can you advise which of these answers would be best with nginx installed with sudo - here is a checklist I am putting together so I can repeat in future  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n6ZIIYI0fmIOVkwtMcxuhfRXLrcuPB4N7KeVI3BfDCw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @tim-higham that depends on what are you trying to achieve. If you need multiple php versions for different users (for example, some of them have legacy project which require older version), then you need to use 2nd approach. If you installing version which is not in packages of your distro, but okay if every user will have same version, thats another case and you should take 1nd path. 3rd one is pretty specific and I cannot name typical use-case of it.

Comment: thanks for your answer and further comments. The main required result here is to create a single user webserver on linux which should run the latest php but also have the ability to run legacy php, for example where there are deprecated functionality like old mysql authentication